# configuring Spring Boot with Hibernate JPA and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am new to Spring Boot but I have experience on Spring.

I have a working starter Spring Boot project. Now I want to connect it to Postgres DB and be able to use general queries. Specifically quite often we write following types of code in Spring(in DAO):

```
@Autowired 
SessionFactory factory;

    @Override
    public String daoFunction1() {
        Session session = null;
        try{
            session = factory.openSession();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee where employeeId=10");
            //where Employee is a model/persistance class already added
            Employee result = (Employee)query.list();
    .....//whatever else is required follows
    }

    //OR

    @Override
    public String daoFunction1() {
        Session session = null;
        try{
            session = factory.openSession();
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery("Select * from cametaschema.test");
            List<Object[]> result = query.list();
    .....//whatever else is required follows
    }
```

Question : **Can someone please tell me what is standard method of doing the same in Spring Boot and for doing that what all i will need to add in different files(like which all dependencies and annotations etc).**

I know for you putting all code here for some Tom Dick and Harry like me will take too much of time, But your answer Just in words (saying include this there) can make my day and save my nights :)

Please note I want to be able to use both HQL queries and Native SQL queries on using same session. I don't want to use Entity manager for HQL and session(as mentioned above) for Native SQL queries.

I have been searching on Internet for quite long but no one clearly told what I am trying to get (I know may be I couldn't reach a proper resource because It's a very general thing). Most tutorials just show configuring Hibernate JPA with CRUDRepository etc.

Any suggestion would be great help for me

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Just keep writing this kind of daoFunctionN-s since Spring Boot doesn't discourage you from doing that. Spring Boot's purpose is to provide plenty amount of functionality out-of-the-box without writing tons of boilerplate code and configurations.

Comment: Shevchenko - Okay, I agree that my understanding is not proper, But please tell how can I achieve this in Spring Boot. I just want to use HQL and Native SQL both.

Answer (score 0):

@Nikolay surely answered to bring me on track to follow standard and get best of Spring Boot. But being bound by mu organization's recommendations, I had to do something similar what we do in Spring. Here is how finally I achieved it.

1. Get Session factory by injecting following bean in your configuration:

   @Bean public SessionFactory sessionFactory(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) { return emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class); }
2. Add EntityScan and ComponentScan to your configuration class

   @EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.app.persistence"}
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app" })
3. Go ahead and use any HQL queries just like Spring:

   @Autowired
       SessionFactory factory;

   ```
   @Override
   public String check() {
       Session session = null;
       try {
           session = factory.openSession();
           Query query = session.createQuery("from Test");
           List<Test> res = query.list();
           Test sing = res.get(0);
           return sing.getName();

       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Exception in Dao");
           e.printStackTrace();
           throw e;
       } finally {
           if (session != null) {
               session.close();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Note: I am assuming that other things like configuring DataSource and all have been taken care already.

Anyone can feel free to correct me if my understanding or way was wrong.

But it worked well for me this way!! :)